# Can not get ImageView to display

Tags: android, xml

My intent is to create a list of widgets on a scroll view, with an ImageView in the centre of the screen behind them.  Here is what I have, there will be more buttons when all is said and done:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:contentDescription="@string/description"
    android:src="@drawable/myImage" 
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:scaleType="centerInside" />


<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"        
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:gravity="center"        
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">


        <Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/newButton"
            style="@style/homeScreenButton"
            android:text="@string/new_profile" />

        <Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/loadButton"
            style="@style/homeScreenButton"
            android:text="@string/load_profile" />

        <Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/calculatorButton"
            style="@style/homeScreenButton"
            android:text="@string/calculator" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

On eclipse's xml graphical layout interpreter, the screen is shown as expected.  The same is true with the 2 different emulators that I tried, Android 2.2 and Android 4.0.3.  But when I send to my actual device, Droid 4 w/Android 4.1.2 the **image simply does not show up**.  I even tried making the ScrollView transparent (android:alpha="0") thinking that it was somehow covering the image up, but nothing.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try eliminating this line from ImageView,

```
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

it should be present only in the **RelativeLayout**

so your xml file become

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView 
android:contentDescription="@string/description"
android:src="@drawable/myImage" 
android:id="@+id/imageView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:scaleType="centerInside" />


<ScrollView 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_centerVertical="true"        
android:background="@android:color/transparent">

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:gravity="center"        
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">


    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/newButton"
        style="@style/homeScreenButton"
        android:text="@string/new_profile" />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/loadButton"
        style="@style/homeScreenButton"
        android:text="@string/load_profile" />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/calculatorButton"
        style="@style/homeScreenButton"
        android:text="@string/calculator" />

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Nope, nothing changed when I removed that line. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the code was fine.  My problem was that the image was in /res/drawable but it needed to be in /res/drawable-hdpi.